# How to harden a drupal8 instance in production?

Tags: php, security, drupal-8, dev-to-production

I have built my first drupal8 site (not e-commerce). What should I do to make sure my drupal instance is sufficiently secure in PROD?

as an example for drupal7 i used to:

- make the docroot read-only
- make a symlink from files to a filesro outside of docroot
- rename install.php to install.php_ORIGINAL
- change the db password to something supper long
- ...

Comment: Do you have server access? Because one of my evil tricks is to just disable any and all FTP accounts while I'm not working on it... It works miracles, I tell ya.

Comment: SSL, whitelisting only one ip address for the admin, (yours)

Comment: two great suggestions thank you. i am now studying : https://www.drupal.org/project/guardr